# I want assistance on Taskkill command

Tags: cmd, explorer, taskkill

I have below command and saved it as a **.bat** file.

**taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe**

**start /realtime chrome.exe**

now I want to add some further command so that upon closing google chrome **Windows Explorer** process gets started automatically.

Comment: add a `/wait` to the `start` command and as next line start explorer (with just `explorer.exe`)

Comment: So, hi, and welcome to Stack Over Flow, this question have 2 commands, and this do is kill explorer and start chrome, ok,  but in explanation, your need, I´m not sure if i understand, so, you need is in this sequence: 1) kill explorer, 2) start chrome,  **still the same bat**, 3) see that chrome killed, 4) perform more tasks/commands, **in same bat**? there is?

Comment: @Stephan Sir, please combine my code and your code and paste it below in bold. Actually,  I don't know where to add /wait command in batch file.  So please provide complete code that I can use to create a new batch file.  My computer processor is slow that's why I am using /realtime command. Is it good enough to use /high command instead of /realtime command.

Answer (score 0):

use `start /wait` to wait until the started process is finished/exited. Then just execute `explorer.exe`

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
start /realtime /wait chrome.exe
explorer.exe
```

Note: I don't think, its a good idea to kill explorer or to start a browser as "realtime", but I see your point: being on a meager system you want to assign every available resource to the task to be done.

([But Chrome might not be the best choice in this case](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-web-browser))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **with administrator privileges**

```bat
start /min taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe 2>nul >nul && start "" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" && start "" /wait /realtime "%windir%\explorer.exe" && start "" /realtime "%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe" /f /im cmd.exe <nul
```

This final part: `start "" /realtime "%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe" /f /im cmd.exe <nul`, can be replace by `call some_bat.bat <nul` with all commands that you need to run.